# Atmosphere: Multiple paths for a ManagedService

Tags: spring, atmosphere

Spring has the concept of multiple RequestMapping paths for a controller. I can't see a way to do something similar with Atmosphere.

We'd like something like:

```
@ManagedService(path={"/api/subscribe/{id}", "/another/api/{id}"})
```

Is there a workaround? We're using Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE, Atmosphere 2.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

File an enhancement here https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/issues that's pretty easy to implement.

-- Jeanfrancois (Atmosphere's lead)